# How to get how many minutes have passed since some time mark

Tags: swift, time, nsdate

I would like that my app would show how much time has passed since some time mark, like Stopwatch. Should I used NSdate?

I've tried using `NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:_)` and as parameter I wanted to chose  `NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: someTimeStamp)` which is not allowed.

I also tried doing it manually, by converting `NSTimeInterval` of current time to `Int` like this:

```
var date = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let time3 = Int(date)
let time4 = Int(someTimeStamp) //NSTimeInterval in Epoch time
let time5 = Double(time3 - time4)
let time6 = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: time5) //This is what I need
```

Although now I am not sure how to properly display `time6`, I could do manually divide by 60 to get minutes and divide by 60 to get hours, but I am pretty sure there has to be simpler way to display how much time has passed since `NSTimeInterval` (preferably in `mm` format if below 60 minutes and in `hh:mm` if above 60 minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(DateYouWantToPassToGetInterval)`

Note the () after the NSDate. The NSDate() instantiates a new NSDate object, and then timeIntervalSinceDate returns the time difference between that and timeAtPress. That will return a floating point value (technically, a NSTimeInterval).

If you want that as truncated to an Int value, you can just use:

`let duration = Int(elapsedTime)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: (Objective C)

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:apptDt
                                              toDate:deliveredDt options:0];
NSInteger seconds = [components second];
NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
NSInteger hours = [components hour];
```

Swift:

```
    let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

    let unitFlags:NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.Hour.union(NSCalendarUnit.Minute).union(NSCalendarUnit.Second)

    let components = gregorian?.components(unitFlags, fromDate: apptDt, toDate:deliveredDt, options: .MatchFirst)

    let seconds = components?.second
    let minute = components?.minute
    let hour = components?.hour

    print("Second: \(seconds), Minutes:\(minute), Hour:\(hour)")
```

Just put starting date in 'fromDate' and 'toDate' current date.

Comment: you may want to provide the code in swift too/instead.

Comment: Thanks, although Swift example would be better, since my code is in Swift and I don't know Objective C

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Bhavuk, here's what I came up with for Swift 4

```
let now = Date()
let yesterday = Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: -86400)
let calendar = Calendar.current
let componentSet: Set = [Calendar.Component.hour, .minute, .second]
let components = calendar.dateComponents(componentSet, from: now, to: yesterday)

let seconds = components.second!
let minutes = components.minute!
let hours = components.hour!

print("Seconds: \(seconds), Minutes:\(minutes), Hours:\(hours)")
```